# RxSwift calling bind fires immediately vs subscribe(onNext: )

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Everything I've read says that `bind(to:)` calls `subscribe(onNext:)` within it. So I assume I should be able to swap out some stuff, but when I use `bind(to:) the thing it's binding to fires immediately. Here's my example:

### ButtonCollectionViewCell

```
class ButtonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var buttonTapped: Observable<Void> = { _buttonTapped.asObservable() }()
    private var _buttonTapped = PublishSubject<Void>()
    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    @IBOutlet private weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var actionButton: UIButton!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        actionButton.rx.tap.bind(to: _buttonTapped).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }

}
```

Now when I do the following below everything works as expected and it prints to the console when I tap the button

### ViewController with a collection view

```
func createButtonCell() {
    let buttonCell = ButtonCollectionViewCell() // there's more code to create it, this is just for simplicity
    buttonCell.buttonTapped.subscribe { _ in
        print("tapped")
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    return buttonCell
}
```

However, if I change the above to:

```
func createButtonCell() {
    let buttonCell = ButtonCollectionViewCell()
    buttonCell.buttonTapped.bind(to: buttonTapped)
    return buttonCell
}

private func buttonTapped(_ sender: Observable<Void>) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

The `"tapped"` is printed out right before I get to the cell when scrolling which I assume is when it's being created.

I don't understand this. I thought I could almost swap out the implementations? I would like to use the second example above there as I think it's neater but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are not identical...

In the first example you have: `.subscribe { _ in print("tapped") }` which is *not* a `subscribe(onNext:)` call. The *last* closure on the subscribe is being used, not the first. I.E., you are calling `subscribe(onDisposed:)`.

Also, your `ButtonCollectionViewCell` is setup wrong. You bind in the `awakeFromNib()` which is only called once, and dispose in the `prepareForReuse()` which is called multiple times. One of the two needs to be move to a more appropriate place...

#### UPDATE

You could either rebind your subject after reseating the disposeBag, or you could just not put the chain in the dispose bag in the first place by doing:

```
_ = actionButton.rx.tap
    .takeUntil(rx.deallocating)
    .bind(to: _buttonTapped)
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Where would you suggest I move the binding to in the cell setup?